# VBA Functions and variables

Tags: excel, function, vba, variables

I have a question about variables and functions in VBA.  I'm not going to include exactly what the project is in hopes that the initial question won't get to obscure.  I can explain the project this will be used for if requested.

Is it possible to create universal variables in VBA so that all functions can use them?

Ex:

```
Dim testVariable As String
Dim newVariable As String

testVariable = "A"

Function testFunction() As String
    ....
    newVariable = testVariable
End Function
```

As of now, testVariable (when it is in the function) is "Empty"

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but the value assignments must occur within procedures:

```
Public testVariable As String
Public newVariable As String

Sub SetTestVariable()
    testVariable = "A"
End Sub

Function testFunction() As String
    ....
    newVariable = testVariable
End Function
```

Keep in mind that it is generally bad programming practice to use a lot of global variables.  You want to limit the scope of your variables to where they will be used.  For more information about scope in VBA see this Microsoft KnowledgeBase article: [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141693)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked perfectly.  As it turns out I do have a lot of variables that I need to use in many different functions as well as the main Sub.  I feel like Private might fix that problem so it's only module level.  Do you have any advice for what kind of assignment I should use?  Right now I have ten variables that need to be global with a high potential that more will be added.  Thanks again

Comment: @Jesse Smothermon - A class would be a logical choice. In addition, you can encapsulate the initialization of the variables into the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

Leave the variables out of any sub/function, so they become Globals

Then, call an init function before you run any code that contains the default settings, such as the code

```
Sub InitGlobalVars
    testVariable = "A"
End Sub

Sub MyProjectMain
    InitGlobalVars
    ....
    ... rest of code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> > Is it possible to create universal variables in VBA so that all functions can use them?

Yes, although you need to declare the scope as stated by mwolf02. *However*, what you cannot do in VBA is populate them outside of a function or procedure call like you can with VBScript.

In addition, if you really need global variables, you should derive a naming scheme that differentiates global variables from locally declared variables (e.g. prefix them with `g_`). You can get this confusing scenario:

```
Public testVariable as String

Public Sub Main()
    Call Foo()
    Call Bar()
End Sub

Public Sub Foo()
    testVariable = "Foo"
End Sub

Public Sub Bar()
    Dim testVariable As String
    testVariable = "Bar"
End Sub
```

The value of the `testVariable` will be "Foo" even though `Bar` was called later. In fact, there is no way to reference the global variable `testVariable` from within Bar since it has declared a local variable with the same name.

Comment: Awesome point with the prefix idea.... didn't occur to me that you wouldn't be able to change the variable like that later.  Thank you

Comment: This points out another Bad Practice that the VB family of languages let you trip yourself up with--locally declared variables do *not* have to have unique names vis a vis variables iwht broader scope. The narrower-scoped variable just "stands in front of" the broader one.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use global *constants* rather than *variables*.

```
Public Const TESTVARIABLE = "A"
```

I believe it fits better your question rather than setting the value within a specific function.

Obs1.: Global constants are (usually) stored in capital letters.

Obs2.: You cannot set a *global* constant within a worksheet code. Use a specific module (global.bas, for instance) to do it.

Rgds

Answer (score 0):

Very brief example:

```
Dim testVariable As String
Dim newVariable As String

Sub setVariable(ByVal x as string)
    testVariable = x
End Sub

Function testFunction() As String
    testFunction = testVariable
End Function

Sub test()
    Call setVariable("A")
    MsgBox testFunction()
    Call setVariable("B")
    MsgBox testFunction()
End Sub
```

As mentioned in other posts: globals are a bad practice, and a value has to be assigned inside sub/functions. They should also be defined at the beginning of the module.